# Mathematica call CompiledFunction from Python with Listable and Parrallelization attributes

Tags: export, compile, python, code-generation, c-codegenerator

I have a CompiledFunction e.g. this:

```
waveform[u_, θ_, φ_] := u*Sin[θ]*Cos[φ]
waveformComp := 
 With[{code = N[waveformTest[u, θ, φ]]}, 
  Compile[{{u, _Real}, {θ, _Real}, {φ, _Real}}, code, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True]]
```

Now I want to call this function from Python with numpy arrays using the listable attribute.
Using Export I was able to extract the function to C code:

```
Export["waveform.c", waveformComp]
```

But what do I do now how can I import it into python?
An example python code that should work using SIMD instructions would be:

```
import numpy as np
import waveform
res = waveform(np.array([0,1]), np.array([0, np.pi]), np.array([np.pi,2*np.pi]))
```

Comment: Don't do that. Better try [_numba_](https://numba.pydata.org) to compile directly from the Python lanuage. It is also much easier to use than `Compile`: You merely have to add the decoration `@njit` your function implementation. Also parallelizing loops is very easy with _numba_.

Comment: But my function is extremely long and is given as symbolic expression in mathematica. I now need the function for a simulation in python and I would prefer to call the function directly instead of just exchanging the data. I don't think numba will help me in compiling mathematica functions right?

Comment: Okay, that is somewhat in the gray area. Mathematica is indeed much better in converting symbolic expressions into code. (However, _Mathematica_ inserts also quite some garbage into the C code so that I am not sure whether the C compiler can vectorize it automatically.) You can try to do the same with _Sympy_ and _numba_. I tried that a couple of times for a few projects. It was always a pain in the neck, but it worked.